# Remove all duplicated rows apart from one

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have seen this question asked but feel this is slightly different to others and any help is appreciated. Table of data as below:-

| Uid | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 | Col 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 13 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 25262 | 0 |
| 6 | 13 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 25302 | 0 |
| 7 | 13 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 678 | 0 |
| 8 | 13 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 727 | 0 |
| 9 | 13 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 13 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 13 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 13 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 1000 | 0 |
| 13 | 13 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 1100 | 0 |
| 14 | 13 | 1259 | 1179 | 742 | 1200 | 0 |

- If Col 1-4 match and col 5 is all 0's (UID's 1-4) then update Col 6 to 1 except for one row (can be any one).
- If Col 1-4 match and col 5 has a value > 0 plus some 0's (UID's 5-11) then update Col 6 to 1 for all duplicates with 0 in Col 5 (Uid's 9-11).
- If Col 1-4 match and col 5 has a value > 0 and no rows with 0 (Uids 12-14) then keep all of them and nothing to be updated in Col 6.

I hope the above makes sense and any questions then please ask.

The table is ordered correctly so have tried a cursor to loop through but have not got the logic correct.

Edit - "The table is ordered correctly" - This is built on a temporary table for the time being which was created using group by and order by so the duplicates are in order

Edit 2 - SQLSERVER 2014 and no negative numbers in Col 5

Comment: *"The table is ordered correctly"* tables don't have an order; the order of the data is determined by the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this should cover all your cases. Use window functions in a CTE, then update that CTE directly.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      MaxCol5 = FIRST_VALUE(Col5) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
                  ORDER BY Col5 DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),
      rn      = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
                  ORDER BY Col5 DESC)
      
    FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE cte
SET Col6 = 1
WHERE Col5 = 0
  AND (maxCol5 > 0 OR rn > 1);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/dIKPteUN)

This assumes there are no negative numbers in `Col5`. Otherwise use

```sql
MaxCol5 = COUNT(NULLIF(Col5, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4),
```

Comment: You assumed correct there are no negative numbers. Answers in the fiddle look perfect! When trying to implement I have an error at FIRST_VALUE as it is not a recognized built-in function name and syntax error at ROWS.  This is SQL Server 2014 (I should have put that in the original question so apologies). Plus I need to read up on window functions and CTE. Thanks for your help